# I am getting error while providing access to user

Tags: mysql, sql

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to 'root'@'10.113.49.246' identified by 'admin'
```

Here i am getting error :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by 'admin' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1

Comment: I think while giving privileges you don't need to specify "identified by". Its required when you create a user.

Comment: Database type and version? MySQL/MariaDB which version?

Comment: Unrelated, I sincerely hope that you're not making the password to your root account 'admin'

Comment: The version is 8.0.11.